# PySide: Can't get QPainter() to save it's state and restore it on new paintEvent

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to make a very basic image creator using PySide. But I'm having some troubles to draw things.

This is the portion of my script responsible for the draw area:

```
class Area(QWidget):

   global x1
   global y1
   global x2
   global y2
   try:
      x1
   except NameError:
      x1=0
   try:
      y1
   except NameError:
      y1=0

   try:
      x2
   except NameError:
      x2=100
   try:
      y2
   except NameError:
      y2=100

   def mousePressEvent(self, me):
      global x1     
      global y1
      x1 = me.x()
      y1 = me.y()

   def mouseMoveEvent(self, mo):
      global x2
      global y2
      x2 = mo.x()
      y2 = mo.y()
      self.update()

   def paintEvent(self, pe):
      global paint
      paint = QPainter()
      paint.begin(self)
      paint.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)
      paint.save()
      paint.restore()

blankarea = Area()
blankarea.show()
```

Basicaly, what the script does is just draw a line based on mouse events. However, every time the mouse click event occurs (responsible for start a line) it erases the line previously made, even after using QPainter.save() and QPainter.restore(). What could be causing this problem?

Comment: save() and restore() is not about saving what you painted (which isn't stored in the painter but on the paint device, is volatile and needs to repainted in each paint event), but to save the configuration of the painter, i.e. brushes, colors, line widths, transformations etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paintEvent()` method is repainting the entire widget every time it is called. The drawing from the previous calls is completely replaced with the results of each future `paintEvent()` call.

If you want the effect you are describing, you will need to accumulate the points and draw the entire sequence of them each time.

From the docs:
http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.paintEvent

> When the paint event occurs, the update region has normally been
>   erased, so you are painting on the widget's background.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you painting on a `QWidget` when you have all the [graphics view framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview.html)  to play with?

Simple line-drawing example:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.view = View(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

class View(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.viewport().rect()))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self._start = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self._start))
        end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
        self.scene().addItem(
            QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem(QtCore.QLineF(start, end)))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an example. I read the documentation many times, but I did not bothered to read about the graphics view framework.